# Write metadata to both jpg and png

Tags: c#, image

I need to add a metadata tag (description) to uploaded images.

I have found out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1764913/6776 which works great for JPG files, but not for PNG.

```
private string Tag = "test meta data";

private static Stream TagImage(Stream input, string type)
{
    bool isJpg = type.EndsWith("jpg", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || type.EndsWith("jpeg", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    bool isPng = type.EndsWith("png", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    BitmapDecoder decoder = null;

    if (isJpg)
    {
        decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(input, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    }
    else if (isPng)
    {
        decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(input, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    }
    else
    {
        return input;
    }

    // modify the metadata
    BitmapFrame bitmapFrame = decoder.Frames[0];
    BitmapMetadata metaData = (BitmapMetadata)bitmapFrame.Metadata.Clone();
    metaData.Subject = Tag;
    metaData.Comment = Tag;
    metaData.Title = Tag;

    // get an encoder to create a new jpg file with the new metadata.      
    BitmapEncoder encoder = null;
    if (isJpg)
    {
        encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    }
    else if (isPng)
    {
        encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    }

    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapFrame, bitmapFrame.Thumbnail, metaData, bitmapFrame.ColorContexts));

    // Save the new image 
    Stream output = new MemoryStream();
    encoder.Save(output);

    output.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return output;
}
```

It works great when I upload a jpg, but with a png, at the `metaData.Subject = Tag` line, it throws a `System.NotSupportedException` (this codec does not support the specified property).

## Update

It seems I have to use a different method based on the image format:

```
if (isJpg)
{
    metaData.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif:{uint=270}", Tag);
}
else
{
    metaData.SetQuery("/tEXt/{str=Description}", Tag);
}
```

Based on [the available formats' queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the first should work for both formats. The second doesn't really work either (it creates the metadata in the image but does not save its value).

If I try to use the first method (`/app1/ifd/exif`) for PNG, at the `encoder.Save` line I get a not supported exception, "no imaging component suitable".

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but I think there's a mistake in your isJpg = statement. I assume you want to test for ".jpg" or ".jpeg", but you test for ".jpg" twice.

Comment: Yes it's been fixed in the code since then, but not in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using [pngcs](https://code.google.com/p/pngcs/) library (you need to rename the downloaded dll to "pngcs.dll")

Here is how I implemented it:

```
    using Hjg.Pngcs;  // https://code.google.com/p/pngcs/
using Hjg.Pngcs.Chunks;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MarkerGenerator.Utils
{
    class PngUtils
    {

        public string getMetadata(string file, string key)
        {

            PngReader pngr = FileHelper.CreatePngReader(file);
            //pngr.MaxTotalBytesRead = 1024 * 1024 * 1024L * 3; // 3Gb!
            //pngr.ReadSkippingAllRows();
            string data = pngr.GetMetadata().GetTxtForKey(key);
            pngr.End();
            return data; ;
        }


        public static void addMetadata(String origFilename, Dictionary<string, string> data)
        {
            String destFilename = "tmp.png";
            PngReader pngr = FileHelper.CreatePngReader(origFilename); // or you can use the constructor
            PngWriter pngw = FileHelper.CreatePngWriter(destFilename, pngr.ImgInfo, true); // idem
            //Console.WriteLine(pngr.ToString()); // just information
            int chunkBehav = ChunkCopyBehaviour.COPY_ALL_SAFE; // tell to copy all 'safe' chunks
            pngw.CopyChunksFirst(pngr, chunkBehav);          // copy some metadata from reader 
            foreach (string key in data.Keys)
            {
                PngChunk chunk = pngw.GetMetadata().SetText(key, data[key]);
                chunk.Priority = true;
            }

            int channels = pngr.ImgInfo.Channels;
            if (channels < 3)
                throw new Exception("This example works only with RGB/RGBA images");
            for (int row = 0; row < pngr.ImgInfo.Rows; row++)
            {
                ImageLine l1 = pngr.ReadRowInt(row); // format: RGBRGB... or RGBARGBA...
                pngw.WriteRow(l1, row);
            }
            pngw.CopyChunksLast(pngr, chunkBehav); // metadata after the image pixels? can happen
            pngw.End(); // dont forget this
            pngr.End();
            File.Delete(origFilename);
            File.Move(destFilename, origFilename);

        }

        public static void addMetadata(String origFilename,string key,string value)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            data.Add(key, value);
            addMetadata(origFilename, data);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: How do you handle a case when we have only one channel? pngr.ImgInfo.Channels == 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

The library CompactExifLib can write EXIF tags in JPEG, TIFF and PNG files:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5251929/CompactExifLib-Access-to-EXIF-Tags-in-JPEG-TIFF-an

It is written purely in C# and can be used for free.

Note: I am the author of this library.

Answer (score -4):

The PNG-format does not support metadata  :(

But [XMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) does, which might be of help when converting between JPEGs, with EXIF-metadata, and PNG.

Comment: According the [Portable Network Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Ancillary_chunks) topic on Wikipedia, PNG can store Metadata. So I am not sure why you think it cannot.

Comment: I suspect it is because `PngBitmapEncoder`'s Metadata member is unsettable. In particular `encoder.Metadata = new BitmapMetadata("png");` generates an exception "The designated BitmapEncoder does not support global metadata."