# C# - Is there any way to add some custom data/identifier to a file in windows (net core console app)?

Tags: c#, windows, file, .net-core, metadata

I have a .net core 2.2 console app which working with files on windows.
I would like to add some custom metadata to a file so I'll be able to recognize the file with no dependency on name / path.
Trying to avoid using shell scripts or dsofile.dll.

Comment: Please always provide a Minimal Reproducible Example of what you tried first to help you better. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think your only option is DSOfile or you need to make sure that you file supports metadata. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235190/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-metadata-to-file?rq=1

Comment: What this app is doing? The app itself can maintain this data itself, you can use full filename alone as a key or using size+hash combo to support renamed/moved file.